# How to auto-fill day column from date without dragging in google sheets?

Tags: date, google-sheets, autofill, weekday

In Google Sheets, I have two columns, date and day, when date is entered i want day to be filled automatically,

For example, if you set `A1` as `1/12/21` then day cell should change to Wednesday.

How do we do that?

Comment: @carlesgg97 Kindly check sir

Comment: What does `day` refer to here? Day of the month?

Comment: Yes, if you set A1 as 1/12/21 then day cell should change to wednesday

Answer (score 2):

Use [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) to convert your date to the desired format, where:

> dddd for the full name of the day of the week.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,TEXT(A2:A,"dddd")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much sir

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dates are in `A2:A`, put this formula in `B2`:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,DAY(A2:A)))
```

Comment: Its returning date, if A2 is 30/11/21 then with this formula its showing 30 as result i want Tuesday as answer.